# inputs value converter overriding change.trigger event

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have an input field which accepts 10 consecutive digits, and formats the number into a phone number of xxx-xxx-xxxx format once the last digit is entered. IT also allows the user to enter the number in the mentioned format as wel as a 10 digit sequence.

I also have a popup that appears once the user changes the value(in this case if the value is not the same as before when the user tabs/clicks off the field). Since i added the value converter, whenever the number is formatted on the 10th digit, the change event doesn't fire anymore. the strange thing is if the user types the number in the format it will eventually end up in, the event will fire as expected.

**phone-format.js**

```js
export class PhoneNumberValueConverter {
  toView(value) {
    return value.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');
  }
}
```

**input field**

```html
    <input id="phNumber" value.bind="phone | phoneFormat" change.trigger="showModal();"></input>
```

**showModal();**

```js
    showModal() {
        if(this.hasChanged && this.yesRadio){
            $('#updateModal').modal();
        }
    }
```

Is the value converter firing a change event thats taking priority over my own on the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MDN, the `change` event is supposed to fire when the input element loses focus after its value was changed.

When the 10th digit is entered your value converter formats the value, causing the binding system to apply the formatted value to the input. Because the last thing that happens before the input loses focus is the value being set programmatically (vs via user input), the criteria for the `change` event to fire is not met.

Try using the `blur` event instead since your change handler is already checking whether the value was changed.